# How to set tab spacing in shape/paragraph with python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am setting up a final slide with table of content containing all slide titles and related slide numbers from presentation.

In this case I work with python-pptx 0.6.18 & Python 3.7. So far I've managed to split title and page number with tab sign, however I don't know where should I look for setting tab spacing for those sign.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Cm, Pt

path_to_presentation = 'your/path/to/file.pptx'
prs = Presentation(path_to_presentation)

list_of_titles = []
list_of_slide_pages = []

...
# some code populating both above mentioned lists
...

# create new slide
tslide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[1]
toc_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(tslide_layout)

# add content to TOC slide
toc_slide.shapes.title.text = 'Table of contents'

for numer, title in enumerate(list_of_titles):
    paragraph = toc_slide.shapes[1].text_frame.paragraphs[numer]
    paragraph.text = title+'\t'+str(list_of_slide_pages[numer])
    paragraph.level = 0
    paragraph.runs[0].font.size = Pt(18)
    toc_slide.shapes[1].text_frame.add_paragraph()

# save presentation
prs.save('your/path/to/file_with_TOC.pptx')
```

I am looking for parameters to set distance and alignment for tab stops in this shape/text_frame/paragraph or any other trick to elegantly bypass these parameters in a different way giving the desired final result. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This would be accomplished with something like `paragraph.tab_stops.add_tab_stop()` if that existed, but unfortunately API support for tab-stop editing has not yet been added to `python-pptx`.